# Delete duplicate dictionary form a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to find duplicate directories from a list of dictionaries and delete one of them but it's generating an error. name, age, group only all 3 should be same values to take it as duplicate dictionary. Without append to a new list of dictionaries

```
a = [
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 21,"group":"sdd","points":0},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5,"group":"sdo","points":0},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7,"group":"spp","points":0},
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 21,"group":"sdd","points":0},
  {"name": "Buke", "age": 31,"group":"pool","points":0}
]

print(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
  for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
    if a[i] == a[j]:
      a.pop[j]
      

print(a)
```

Comment: To be clear you don't care if the value of `"points"` is the same or not?

Comment: yes, I don't care the value of "points"

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, the duplicate is only when name, age and group match:

```py
a = [
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 21, "group": "sdd", "points": 0},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "group": "sdo", "points": 0},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "group": "spp", "points": 0},
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 21, "group": "sdd", "points": 0},
    {"name": "Buke", "age": 31, "group": "pool", "points": 0},
]

out, seen = [], set()
for d in a:
    tpl = d["name"], d["age"], d["group"]
    if tpl not in seen:
        seen.add(tpl)
        out.append(d)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 21, "group": "sdd", "points": 0},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "group": "sdo", "points": 0},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "group": "spp", "points": 0},
    {"name": "Buke", "age": 31, "group": "pool", "points": 0},
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert each `dict` to a `tuple`, then apply `set` to remove duplicates. At the end back to the `list` of `dict`s.

```
a = [
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 21,"group":"sdd","points":0},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5,"group":"sdo","points":0},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7,"group":"spp","points":0},
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 21,"group":"sdd","points":0},
  {"name": "Buke", "age": 31,"group":"pool","points":0}
]

a_new = list(map(dict, set(tuple(dct.items()) for dct in a)))
print(a_new)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Mark', 'age': 5, 'group': 'sdo', 'points': 0},
 {'name': 'Tom', 'age': 21, 'group': 'sdd', 'points': 0},
 {'name': 'Buke', 'age': 31, 'group': 'pool', 'points': 0},
 {'name': 'Pam', 'age': 7, 'group': 'spp', 'points': 0}]
```

---

*Explanation*:
In python, a set contains no duplicates. Thus, you can convert a list to an set (and optionally back to a list again) to remove duplicates.
In your case, the simple conversion `a = list(set(a))` is not sufficient, since `a` contains dictionaries, which aren't hashable (requirement for sets). Therefore, we first map the dictionaries to tuples of key-value tuples.

This solution is short, but not great performance-wise, as we have to iterate through `a` multiple times.

Comment: I dont see its as required by OPs data, but identically valued dicts may have different field orders, requiring a `sorted` step in the pipeline by the items.  Also OP only matches identity to 3 fields not all.  Still a useful technique in most cases tho.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me an answer but I want do this without append to a list